# How to make an Inspector field accept references to instances of different classes

Tags: unity, c#

I have a variable in my Unity script, and I want to be able to assign to that variable an object of one of two different classes; for instance:

```
[SerializedField] private MyClass1 myClass1;

[SerializedField] private MyClass2 myClass2;
```

I need something like:

```
[SerializedField] private GeneralClassVariable myClass1; // or myClass2
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question completely, but if `myClass1` and `myClass2` are completely like each other, then they both can be like what you said, so what's the problem?

Comment: @ArianKeshvari they are not totally the same. I thinking of make an abstract class to store this variable, but this is the problem which I described. This variable going be passed as a parameter for same function for two classes. But there are some differences inside of every class...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to achieve what's called "polymorphism", where you have different classes providing parallel functionality and you can swap them out without modifying the code that uses them. There are different ways to achieve this in Unity, so if you can **edit your question** to give us more details about the game feature you're trying to implement this way, we can help you select an approach that will fit your application well.